# apache nifi 1.10 site-to-site (http) error: Unable to refresh Remote Group's peers due to null

Tags: apache-nifi

I'd like to let nifi eat its own bulletin message by using the "SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask" controller. here is my setting [nifi s2s bulletinReportingTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDUMS.png)
however although nifi instance can eat the bulletin message but it always raise warning massage like:

*23:47:37 CSTWARNINGdf68bf40-016e-1000-b458-a0a98bf3ebc6
SiteToSiteBulletinReportingTask[id=df68bf40-016e-1000-b458-a0a98bf3ebc6] org.apache.nifi.remote.client.PeerSelector@2ae7fbef Unable to refresh Remote Group's peers due to null*

Any advice?

PS.
there is "state" folder under "nifi/" and i also manually created "state" folder under "nifi/conf/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue here --- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6886

Comment: this issue not happened in apache nifi 1.7.0